# Facebook OAuth - is there a way to 'clear' previous user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a Windows Phone App and am using the [OAuth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) interface.

When I navigate to the auth url the first time it shows the login UI.  Subsequent times I'm redirected directly to my facebook app page with showing the login UI.  Presumably because the login is cached in a cookie or something.  All good so far.

The problem comes in when I need to switch users.  Is there a way to force the facebook oauth url to clear previous creds and show the login screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the user out of Facebook using the url below:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&confirm=1&next=REDIRECT
```

Comment: @Spencer I can confirm that Facebook often change their API/functionality and that this trick no longer works. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @BeRecursive from what I've tested, the confirm variable doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Now, in order to log a user out of Facebook you need to use this url:

```
"https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next="+your_site_url_registered _on_fb+"&access_token="+accessToken
```